# Цикл в БД sqlite3 ходит по кругу

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Есть вот такой цикл, который берет значения из БД sqlite3

```
def cycle_wbot (count=1):
    try:
        def zapros1(count):
            user_chat_id = sqlite3.connect('wb_id_plus_api.db')
            cursor = user_chat_id.cursor()
            user_id = cursor.execute('''SELECT user_id FROM id_api WHERE id = "{}" '''.format(count)).fetchone()
            api_id = cursor.execute('''SELECT api_x64 FROM id_api WHERE id = "{}" '''.format(count)).fetchone()
            if user_id:
                if api_id:
                    pass
            count += 1
            cycle_wbot(count)
        zapros1(count)
    except TypeError:
        count += 1
        cycle_wbot(count)
    except telebot.apihelper.ApiException:
        count += 1
        cycle_wbot(count)
    except RecursionError:
        raise
cycle_wbot()
```

Он работает, однако проходит по строкам БД два раза, соответственно выводит информацию два раза. Подскажите почему не завершается после первого раза, когда дойдет до максимального количества строк в БД, вроде как должна выскочить ошибка RecursionError. После первого раза, он возвращает снова Count=0 и погнал

Comment: (1) Написать рекурсию вместо цикла так себе идея. (2) `pass` - это не `return`, это просто пустой оператор. Соответственно, даже если нет `user_id`, он продолжает вызывать `cycle_wbot`. (3) В целом даже такой код не должен переключаться в `0` в конце перебора, так что я думаю, что ты сюда принёс один код, а запускаешь другой.

Comment: Конечно, всегда так делаю. Проверяю на вшивость, запускаю один код и чтобы поглумиться над всеми пишу другой в вопрос.